# NSTimer does not stop when invalidate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nstimer

I want to check if the application is idle (user doesn't take any action for the last 30 minutes) and log out the user.

For that I have an event manager that resets a timer.

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {      
    if(event == nil) {
        [self resetIdleTimer];
    } else {
        [super sendEvent:event];

        // Only want to reset the timer on a Began touch or an Ended touch, to reduce the number of timer resets.
        NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
        if ([allTouches count] > 0) {
            // allTouches count only ever seems to be 1, so anyObject works here.
            UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
            if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
                [self resetIdleTimer];
        }
    }
}

- (void)resetIdleTimer {
    if (self.idleTimer) {
        [self.idleTimer invalidate];
        self.idleTimer = nil;
    }

    NSInteger maxTime = 60*30; //30 minutes

    self.idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:maxTime target:self selector:@selector(checkIfIdleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (void)checkIfIdleTimerExceeded {

    theProfileManager = [[ProfileManager alloc] init];
    theProfile = [theProfileManager getProfile];

    if( ! [[theProfile getStatus]isEqualToString:@"u1"]) {
        if( ! [[theProfile getTheUser] isUnlimitedLogin]) {
            theProfile = nil;
            theUserManager = [[UserManager alloc] init];
            [theUserManager setCurrentUser:[theProfile getTheUser]];
            [theUserManager setCurrentUserAccount:[[theProfile getTheUser] getTheUserAccount]];
            [theUserManager setCurrentUserSettings:[[theProfile getTheUser] getTheUserSettings]];
            [theUserManager logoutCurrentUser];

            [[MenuItemDataManager alloc] deleteJsonData];

            NSNotification *msg = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"leftPanelMsg" object:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Home"]];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:msg];

            [self performSelector:@selector(loadHomeView:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
        }
    }
    [self resetIdleTimer];

}
```

The `checkIfIdleTimerExceeded` does the log out process.

**Problem:** After 15 minutes I touch the screen, the `resetIdleTime` is called and should restart a new `NSTimer`. But after 15 minutes the application logs the user out.

Thanks for your help.

André.

Comment: Make sure that you have created and invalidated the NSTimer on the same thread. If it is on different threads, it may not work.

Comment: Post the code for checkIfIdleTimerExceeded so that I can have a look

Comment: @ Jamar Zafar : the checkIfIdleTimerExceeded only make the logout.

@ Shanti K : how to be sure that the NSTimer is invalidated on the same thread ?

Comment: @LordStJohn: Check my answer and tell me if it helps.

Comment: Seems after 30 minutes the FIRST NStimer do the logout.

Comment: When is your resetIdleTimer gets called? How are you calling it and when?

Comment: @LordStJohn: Try invaliding the NSTimer the way i have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: NSTimer only works in active mode of the app. So there may be some different issue. Please specify what you wants. How you are capturing events? So that i can help you

Comment: Question : If I log the time like this : DLog(@"idleTime : %@", self.idleTimer); it should show the address of the the Timer, and should be the same at each time ? The address is different on each touch event.

Comment: you **do not** need to set a new timer when the old one invoked the logout session... you **do** need to set a new timer _after_ the next successful login.

Comment: @ Jamal Zafar, I added the missing code

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement of the Touches event. You should do this:

```
 NSSet *allTouchEvents = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouchEvents count] > 0) {
        // allTouchEvents count only ever seems to be 1, so anyObject works here.
        UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouchEvents anyObject]).phase;
        if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan || phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
            [self resetIdleTimer];
    }
```

And in the  resetIdleTimer, The

```
self.idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:maxTime target:self selector:@selector(checkIfIdleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

should be like

```
self.idleTimer  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:maxTime target:self selector:@selector(checkIfIdleTimerExceeded:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

And `checkIfIdleTimerExceeded` should be like:

```
-(void) checkIfIdleTimerExceeded :(NSTimer*)timer
    {

       //Do your all process and invalidate after completion

        [timer invalidate];

    }
```

Comment: Jamal is right, whether this solves the problem or not, a downvote is unjustified.

Comment: If I understand, you invalidate the Time after the time is exceeded, but I have to invalidate it when the user has to touche the screen, that's why the "resetTimer" has been written

Comment: @Jamal: It will be better if you can specify where to write the touch capture block.

Comment: @LordStJohn: I am sure you are following this approach. Have a look at: http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/09/19/timing-out-an-application-due-to-inactivity/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which one of your other methods can be called beside the `–resetIdleTimer` in your workflow when you touch the screen, but that solution works to me as you have described to like getting it worked:

I'm seeing in the log console the `–resetTimer:` will called if I tap a button within 7 secs, it resets the timer properly and creates a new 7 secs timer.

the logout method will call only if I don't touch my button on the screen in 7 secs time, and the timer finally invokes the `–logout:` method.

```
- (void)resetTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSLog(@"reset time...");

    if (timer.isValid) [timer invalidate], _timer = nil;
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.f target:self selector:@selector(logout:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

//

- (void)buttonTouchedUpInside:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"touched...");

    [self resetTimer:_timer];
}

//

- (void)logout:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSLog(@"logout...");

    if (timer.isValid) [timer invalidate], _timer = nil;

    // logout ...
}
```

Comment: So you have a method `resetTimer` which accepts a timer parameter, and  yet you still reference the `_timer` instance variable?  That looks pretty poorly thought-out.

Comment: @trojanfoe, no, not really – just the opposite. if I would set the local `timer` to `nil` only, the `_timer` still keep alive the actual timer in memory until we'd set a new one. in this case I will set a new timer directly, so technically the old one released, but usually we are not really setting up a new timer every case, like in `–logout:` method but we want to release the old one permanently. so, that solution is pretty professionally thought-out, but thanks your opinion. I appreciate it.

Comment: So drop the `timer` parameter and operate on `_timer` exclusively as the option to choose *which* timer to operate on clearly does not exist.

Comment: @trojanfoe, no, I'm not dropping it at all, because I hate such solutions when the callback-methods are not fully implemented, even if we are talking about _one_ timer only in this case. the pattern is the same no matter how many timers we operate with at same time. the only difference'd be throwing the `_timer = nil` away in case of multiple timers, and try to remove the strong pointer from e.g. an array, which stores them temporarily. but defintely bad practice to throwing away the parameter, I'd never recommend to do such poor thing to anyone at all.